# $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-2\pi itf}~ dt \neq $ FT of piecewise representation?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, signal-processing

What's happening here? Why aren't these 2 inputs identical?

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I use the integral, it gives the result for if the rectangular pulse were to the left side of the y axis in the time domain

Comment: Could you expand on what you think is strange?

Comment: @md2perpe Why aren't those 2 inputs identical? Or more specifically why are they producing 2 different outputs when they describe the same waveform in the time domain being transformed

Comment: I spotted it. The wolfram alpha FT is using a positive rather than a negative sign of the exponent

Comment: I was about to ask: Are you using the same definition of the Fourier transform as WolframAlpha does? Check the sign of the exponent.

Comment: @md2perpe I should probably delete the question now right?

Comment: Normally I don't recommend deleting questions. But if you feel too embarrassed, you can. It also is of limited value for others.